# Asynchronous code runs slower than synchronous version in haskell

Tags: haskell, concurrency, benchmarking, io-monad, haskell-criterion

Benchmarking the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-16.2 script --package async --package criterion

import           Control.Concurrent.Async (async, replicateConcurrently_)
import           Control.Monad            (replicateM_, void)
import           Criterion.Main

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain [
    bgroup "tests" [ bench "sync" $ nfIO syncTest
                   , bench "async" $ nfIO asyncTest
                   ]
    ]

syncTest :: IO ()
syncTest = replicateM_ 100000 dummy

asyncTest :: IO ()
asyncTest = replicateConcurrently_ 100000 dummy

dummy :: IO Int
dummy = return $ fib 10000000000

fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```

Gives me this:

```
% ./applicative-v-monad.hs
benchmarking tests/sync
time                 2.120 ms   (2.075 ms .. 2.160 ms)
                     0.997 R²   (0.994 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 2.040 ms   (2.023 ms .. 2.073 ms)
std dev              77.37 μs   (54.96 μs .. 122.8 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 23% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking tests/async
time                 475.3 ms   (310.7 ms .. 642.8 ms)
                     0.984 R²   (0.943 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 527.2 ms   (497.9 ms .. 570.9 ms)
std dev              41.30 ms   (4.833 ms .. 52.83 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 21% (moderately inflated)
```

Where it is apparent that asyncTest runs longer than syncTest.

I would have thought that running expensive actions concurrently will be faster than running them in sequence. Is there some flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Don't have time to write a proper answer but if fib 10000000000 was being evaluated it would take ~ 2^10000000000 steps, not a few milliseconds.  Neither of your tests is forcing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few problems with this benchmark.

#### First of all laziness

As @David Fletcher pointed out, you are not forcing computation of fib. The fix for this problem normally would be as easy as:

```hs
dummy :: IO Int
dummy = return $! fib 10000000000
```

Which is enough to make us wait for eternity. Lowering it to something more manageable is the next thing we should do:

```hs
dummy :: IO Int
dummy = return $! fib 35
```

This normally would be enough, however ghc is too smart and it will see that this computation is really pure and will optimize the loop of 100000 iterations into a single computation and return the same result 100000 times, so in reality it will compute this fib only once. Instead lets make `fib` depend on the number of iteration:

```hs
xs :: [Int]
xs = [1..35]

syncTest :: IO ()
syncTest = mapM_ dummy xs

asyncTest :: IO ()
asyncTest = mapConcurrently_ dummy xs

dummy :: Int -> IO Int
dummy n = return $! fib n
```

#### Next problem is compilation

`stack script` will run the code iterpreted and without threaded environment. So your code will run slow and sequentially. We fix it with manual compilation and some flags:

```sh
$ stack exec --resolver lts-16.2 --package async --package criterion -- ghc -threaded -O2 -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N bench-async.hs
$ stack exec --resolver lts-16.2 -- ./bench-async
```

Of course, for a full blown stack project all these flags go into a cabal file instead and running `stack bench` will do the rest.

#### Last, but not least. Too many threads.

In the question you have `asyncTest = replicateConcurrently_ 100000 dummy`. Unless number of iterations is very low, which it is not, you don't want to use `async` for this because spawning at least a 100000 threads is not free, it is better to use a work stealing scheduler for this type of work load. I specifically wrote a library for this purpose: [`scheduler`](https://github.com/lehins/haskell-scheduler)

Here is an example how to use it:

```hs
import qualified Control.Scheduler as S

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain [
    bgroup "tests" [ bench "sync" $ whnfIO syncTest
                   , bench "async" $ nfIO asyncTest
                   , bench "scheduler" $ nfIO schedulerTest
                   ]
    ]
schedulerTest :: IO ()
schedulerTest = S.traverseConcurrently_ S.Par dummy xs
```

Now this will give us more sensible numbers:

```
benchmarking tests/sync
time                 246.7 ms   (210.6 ms .. 269.0 ms)
                     0.989 R²   (0.951 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 266.4 ms   (256.4 ms .. 286.0 ms)
std dev              21.60 ms   (457.3 μs .. 26.92 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 18% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking tests/async
time                 135.4 ms   (127.8 ms .. 147.9 ms)
                     0.992 R²   (0.980 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 134.8 ms   (129.7 ms .. 138.0 ms)
std dev              6.578 ms   (3.605 ms .. 9.807 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 11% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking tests/scheduler
time                 109.0 ms   (96.83 ms .. 120.3 ms)
                     0.989 R²   (0.956 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 111.5 ms   (108.0 ms .. 120.2 ms)
std dev              7.574 ms   (2.496 ms .. 11.85 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 12% (moderately inflated)
```

Comment: I will upvote this but take out the part where you say there's a largest known fibonacci with only 465 digits, because that's just wrong.  You could make one as big as your hard disk if you wanted.

Comment: @DavidFletcher I removed the comment, because it was wrong indeed. I guess I mixed something up in my head and made that comment without thinking. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You could make the dependence on the count smaller using something like ``35 + (n `rem` 2)``.

Comment: @dfeuer sure. But, you know, this is purely demonstrational, which make it less important that seeing the effect of actual parallelization.